# UICollectionViewCell with tabs

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I would like to add tabs to my UICollectionview Cells. To flip through information pertaining to each cell.

Kind of like the tabs on Safari, but on each cell.

I am relatively new to iOS, I was hoping someone here could point me in the right direction.  I am at a loss to what object I would need to use to embed all of the objects in for each tab.  Can I use several UIViews within a UICollectionViewCell? Or maybe it's a scrollable region thing?

I have been trying to research this for hours and I think I just don't know how to word my search correctly.

Comment: You'll have to create it yourself from scratch. There is no control that will do this out of the box. Use a UIView to control the "tabs" then show/hide different UIViews depending on which "tab" is selected.

Comment: Thanks.  This saved me from a few more hours of fruitless searches.